# Creating distribution variable for transport type from frequency table

Tags: r, stata

I am working with the following table:

`Var1` is of the format location.transport type. Therefore, `A.land` means location `A`, transport type `land`. Frequency is simply the number of times a location used the respective transport_type. `Location_ID` and `Transport_Type` were created in Stata by splitting `Var1`.

```
| Var1    | Frequency | Location_ID | Transport_Type|
|----     |----       | -----       | -----         |
| A.land  | 4         | A           |land           |
| A.air   | 3         | A           |air            |
| A.sea   | 2         | A           |sea            |
| B.sea   | 5         | B           |sea            |
| B.other | 2         | B           |other          |
| B.land  | 2         | B           |land           |
| C.land  | 1         | C           |land           |
| C.air   | 3         | C           |air            |
| C.other | 1         | C           |other          |
```

The goal is to find the distribution of the types of transports from each location A, B, and C.
I wish to create four variables: Proportion_land, Proportion_sea, Proportion_air, and Proportion_other.

For example, for location A I would want to create something like this:

```
Location |Proportion_land| Proportion_sea | Proportion_air | Proportion_other|
|----    |----           |------          | -----          |-----            |
|A       | 4/9           | 3/9            | 2/9            |0                |
```

Comment: See the `stata` tag wiki for how to post a better question. I imagine that R people have similar advice to mine: provide data in directly readable form (not a table that requires editing) and show the code you tried. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service, but aimed primarily at professional and enthusiast programmers. Beginners are welcome but expected to try writing code after reading about a language.

Comment: In fact the R tag is explicit: Please use minimal reproducible example(s) others can run using copy & paste. Show desired output. Use `dput()` for data & specify all non-base packages with `library()`.

Comment: Thanks Nick, sorry for the inconvenience. I just could not post the question with tables because of an error I could not fix so I just turned the tables into code :S

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but you didn't post code at all!

Answer (score 1):

It is a little unclear what you want here, as you don't provide any directly readable data or any exact code. But with some surgery, I get this version of your example data in Stata:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input str7 Var1 byte Frequency str1 Location_ID str5 Transport_Type
"A.land"  4 "A" "land" 
"A.air"   3 "A" "air"  
"A.sea"   2 "A" "sea"  
"B.sea"   5 "B" "sea"  
"B.other" 2 "B" "other"
"B.land"  2 "B" "land" 
"C.land"  1 "C" "land" 
"C.air"   3 "C" "air"  
"C.other" 1 "C" "other"
end
```

and then what you call for requires not so much new variables as a basic cross-tabulation:

```
. tab Location_ID Transport_Type [fw=Freq], row 
+----------------+
| Key            |
|----------------|
|   frequency    |
| row percentage |
+----------------+

Location_I |               Transport_Type
         D |       air       land      other        sea |     Total
-----------+--------------------------------------------+----------
         A |         3          4          0          2 |         9 
           |     33.33      44.44       0.00      22.22 |    100.00 
-----------+--------------------------------------------+----------
         B |         0          2          2          5 |         9 
           |      0.00      22.22      22.22      55.56 |    100.00 
-----------+--------------------------------------------+----------
         C |         3          1          1          0 |         5 
           |     60.00      20.00      20.00       0.00 |    100.00 
-----------+--------------------------------------------+----------
     Total |         6          7          3          7 |        23 
           |     26.09      30.43      13.04      30.43 |    100.00
```

Answer (score 1):

```
clear
input str7 Var1 byte Frequency str1 Location_ID str5 Transport_Type
"A.land"  4 "A" "land" 
"A.air"   3 "A" "air"  
"A.sea"   2 "A" "sea"  
"B.sea"   5 "B" "sea"  
"B.other" 2 "B" "other"
"B.land"  2 "B" "land" 
"C.land"  1 "C" "land" 
"C.air"   3 "C" "air"  
"C.other" 1 "C" "other"
end

local types land sea air other

* Get frequency for each type
foreach type of local types {
    gen `type' = Frequency if (Transport_Type == "`type'")
}

* Aggregate freq for total and each type on location level
collapse (sum) loc_total=Frequency `types'  , by(Location_ID)

* Calculate proportion for each type
foreach type of local types {
    gen Proportion_`type' = `type' / loc_total
}
```

Comment: Previous answer did not store the results in variables.

Comment: Your `foreach` loop could be replaced by a single `separate` call. Note also `contract` as well as `collapse`. Otherwise this complements my answer; my point is that the OP is asking for a table, despite variables being mentioned too.